# How to solve this Linear Algebra problem involving a system of linear equations?

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

[image: Question 1]

The following is what I have so far.

[image]
I'm not sure how to use my echelon matrix to find out which values for the variables can provide an answer to the question or how to prove it. I was thinking of plugging in arbitrary numbers for $x_3\ y_1\ y_2$ but not sure if this is the way to approach this.

Comment: Uh? What is "the following" you have so far??

Answer (score 1):

Expanded coefficients matrix and its reduction:

$$\begin{pmatrix}1&\!\!-2&1&y_1\\
2&1&q&y_2\\
0&5&\!\!-1&y_3\end{pmatrix}\stackrel{R_2-2R_1}\rightarrow\begin{pmatrix}1&\!\!-2&1&y_1\\
0&5&q-2&y_2-2y_1\\
0&5&\!\!-1&y_3\end{pmatrix}\stackrel{R_3-R_2}\rightarrow$$$${}$$

$$\rightarrow\begin{pmatrix}1&\!\!-2&1&y_1\\
0&5&q-2&y_2-2y_1\\
0&0&1-q&y_3-y_2+2y_1\end{pmatrix}$$

Thus, for example:

$$\text{If}\;\;q=1\implies y_3-y_2+2y_1=0$$

and the system has solution (but not unique! Why?) . Try to take it from here.

Answer (score 0):

If q=1, then you are left with only two equations and three unknowns.  This gives you and infinite number of possible solutions for (y1,y3).  To find the solutions, solve $5x_2-x_3=y_3$ and $x_1-2x_2+x_3=y_1$.

If $q$ does not equal on3, then you have only one solution which is the right most column of your reduced row echelon matrix.

Can you take it from here?

Comment: I'm a little confused on solving for $y_1\ and\ y_3$. For example, I solve for $x_3$ and plug it into the other equation to get $$x_1 - 7x_2 - y_3 = y_1$$. From there is it a matter of just plugging in whatever values I want to find a solution?